# Firefox Mobile Browser is not reading USSD code string written in javascript giving me the exception, but working in other browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox, progressive-web-apps

I have a JavaScript code which has a method:

```js
window.location.href="tel:"+encodeURIComponent("*384*0315#")+"";
```

which should redirect to Dial pad with given string.
Now if I do not write `*` and `#` then it will work fine, but throwing exception when I write `*` and `#`.
In other browsers it's working, but not in the Mozilla Firefox browser.
Please give me response and right advice why it's **not working in Firefox** only?

Comment: Its urgent guys, i know very few have tried with ussd code but let me know your ideas.